# Unable to parse mantissa and exponent value separately

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to separate the base and exponent value separately.I am getting a input from user which is in the form given below.I want to separately store base and exponent
Input-3.54e45

 I want to take base and exponent separate.
I am trying to use stod to convert string to integer but it is giving me in the form base e+ exponent and I don't know how to store them separatey

```
int main() {
    double number;
    string a;
    cin>>a;
    try {
        number=stod(a);
    }
    catch(exception const &e) {
    }
    cout<<number;
}
```

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in your code, you use the variable `counts` when it hasn't been initialized. Local non-static variables that hasn't been initialized have an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: Well it,was for other purpose,removed it

Comment: As for the output of `number`, it's probably a purely presentational issue. Maybe you should try [changing the format](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)?

Comment: I checked the link but there is no information on how I can store base and exponent separately

Comment: @Bing If you wan't them separately, use a `std::string` as input and parse them separately into `int` values using a `std::istringstream`.

Comment: This seems like an X|Y problem, why do you want them separately? What are you getting from your code that you don't like?

Comment: @Ben I want to convert the scientific notation form to normal form

Comment: That rolls you back around to Joachim Pileborg 's suggestion of changing the display format. Leave the double in it's native format, just show it to users differently.

Comment: @Bing Consider improving your question title, that's not useful for future research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to take base and exponent separate.

Then parse them separately, instead of parsing the `double` value in 1st place:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string a = "3.54e45"; // Read a with cin>>a; alternatively

    double mantissa;
    int exponent;
    std::string current_part;

    std::istringstream iss(a);
    getline(iss, current_part, 'e'); // Split off the mantissa
    mantissa = std::stod(current_part);
    getline(iss, current_part); // Get the exponent
    exponent = stoi(current_part);

    std::cout <<  "Mantissa:" << mantissa << ", Exponent: " << exponent << std::endl;
}
```

Output is

```
Mantissa:3.54, Exponent: 45
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fadb0d8c6d728c05)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you in the right way, then you just need a delimiter:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double number;
    string input, base, exponent;
    string delimiter = "e";
    size_t pos = 0;

    std::cout << "Type in a floating-point number: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    number = stod(input);
    std::cout << "\nThe number is: " << number << std::endl;

    pos = input.find(delimiter);
    base = input.substr(0, pos);
    exponent = input.substr(pos, input.length());

    std::cout << "The base is: " << base << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The exponent is: " << exponent << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to have the 'e' character within the exponent, just change the appropriate line to:

```
exponent = input.substr(pos + delimiter.length(), input.length());
```

Output:

[image: Result]

Comment: As you can see from my answer this code could be simplified a lot.